# Why can't I beat Snowy Granius during the quest Antabolis Informant?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

This is my first time playing through Morrowind, but I have played Oblivion before.

In the quest Antabolis Informant, I met a bandit ([Snowy Granius](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Snowy_Granius)) on a bridge. He is a battlemage, can summon a skeleton, and can cast spells.

I tried to kill him with my Khajiit acrobat, and I couldn't hit him.

Then I made a Nord warrior, ignored the skeleton he summoned, and started to slash him repeatedly. Although I did damage to him, I still died before him.

Why is it so hard to kill him? I didn't try to level up because I think I can ignore the advice from Caius Cosades, who said I might need to do some quest from a guild.

Comment: Is this bandit called [**Snowy Granius**](http://images.uesp.net/thumb/c/c9/MW-npc-Snowy_Granius.jpg/180px-MW-npc-Snowy_Granius.jpg)?

Comment: I can't play morrowind now because I am in office, but from the clue I got from the internet, I think he is the guy.

Comment: You may need to find a better weapon.  You are pretty weak early on in morrowind, rushing headfirst into the main quest may get you killed even from just a bunch of cliff racers

Comment: "I didn't try to level up because I think I can ignore the advice from Caius Cosades" Hmm I wonder what the problem is.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, he is a fairly "small fish". On the wiki page you provided you can see that he is only lvl3 with 54hp. That tells me you are probably not even lvl5 yet. Go around, do some stuff, level up a bit and then come back at him. Or alternatively, steal/buy a destruction scroll (spell) somewhere, and cast that at him. Make sure the scroll does more damage than he has HP (some kind of fire touch would probably be the best way to go). You could also drink some potions that would make you stronger in fight. + Get better equipment. It's fairly simple, you just need to get stronger.

PS - Morrowind actually becomes very easy after some time because enemies strength does not scale with your strength so what happens is that you reach a point when nobody can kill you any more.

Answer (score 5):

As this is the first quest on the main quest line, it's one people are going to run into early. There's a few options; you can go around the long way, and approach the dungeon from the other side; alternatively, you can ambush him. You can cross the bridge by jumping onto the edge of the bridge, which will allow you to sneak across without him noticing when it's dark. Unfortunately, you can't get off without alerting him, and in straight combat you'll die. What you can do, though, is get his attention, and stab him through the railing until he dies.

Morrowind is a game of options. There's always something else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Morrowind attacks are HIGHLY dependend on your weapons skill, your current stamina, your agility and (what most people ignore) how hard you swing your weapon, as in how long you hold the button when you attack.

If you start out with low agility, weapon skill and are out of stamina you will miss almost every attack.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with him using hand to hand. When he passes out and falls to the ground from so much beating, switch to a secondary weapon and finish him.

lvl 4
hand-to-hand 54